# Why I get Key error even though column present in pandas?

Tags: python, pandas, casting

My file contain columns as Company, RecordID, Sale etc..When i first try to find its datatype after loading file to pandas dataframe, it lists float/int for few columns. So I change them to string as follows;

```
data = pd.read_csv(filepath)
    print(data.dtypes)

Company Code          object
SiteCode               int64
Product Name          object
RECORD ID             int64
Tank ID                int64
Date                   int64
Sale Volume          float64
Deliveries Volume      int64
Dip Volume           float64
```

Then I change their type as string before writing the output to a file;

```
>   data['RECORD ID'] = data['RECORD ID'].astype(str)
>      data['Tank ID'] = data['Tank ID'].astype(str)
```

here i get;

```
    return self._engine.get_loc(key)
  File "pandas/_libs/index.pyx", line 107, in pandas._libs.index.IndexEngine.get_loc
  File "pandas/_libs/index.pyx", line 131, in pandas._libs.index.IndexEngine.get_loc
  File "pandas/_libs/hashtable_class_helper.pxi", line 1607, in pandas._libs.hashtable.PyObjectHashTable.get_item
  File "pandas/_libs/hashtable_class_helper.pxi", line 1614, in pandas._libs.hashtable.PyObjectHashTable.get_item
KeyError: 'RECORD ID'
```

If i comment recordid and let Tankid to convert, then I get same key error for TankId, why is that?

Here is the sample csv; `SIRA RECORD ID` and `TANK ID` columns giving issue

```
 Company Code,SiteCode,Product Name,SIRA RECORD ID,Tank ID,Date,Sale Volume,Deliveries Volume,Dip Volume
    XXX,20995,27PMAXDSL,3535352,4,20191004,4383.49,12902,16000
    XXX,20995,02ULP,3535351,3,20191004,8221.573,15996,9987.32
    XXX,20995,02ULP,3535350,2,20191004,7303.1,8201,11200
```

Comment: What is `print (data.columns.tolist())` ? Maybe some traling whitespace

Comment: @jezrael No, it prints exactly how I defined without any trailing whitespces

Comment: @jezrael no it is single whitespce..

Comment: Can you share a sample of the CSV file?

Comment: @rdas Added teh sample csv

Comment: Use `SIRA RECORD ID`

Comment: @jezrael yes I use SIRA RECORD ID. For the example I cut 'SIRA' prefix. But I actually use SIRA RECORD ID. Error also gives like; Key error 'SIRA RECORD ID"

Comment: Could not reproduce it with the sample CSV. Very strange indeed.

Comment: Do you want **all** the column types to be `str`?

Comment: @rdas argh?? Im getting struggling with this for 2 hours..will there be any charset issue?

Comment: Seems to be something silly like that. Can you try opening the file with utf-8 & printing out the column names from the dataframe? Maybe even try opening the file in vim to see if there's any stray unicode in there.

Comment: @TrentonMcKinney yes..because orginal datatypes some times pandas identify as int, sometimes float for few files, then when i write the output it adds decimal"*.o". SO i wnat to convert everything to string before writing them in an csv

Comment: hmmm, so if use `print (data.columns.tolist())` what return? If manually copy from output to `df[]` maybe should working

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Instead of manually entering the column names, try the following, as a test:

```py
for col in data.columns:
    data[col] = data[col].astype(str)
```

This should also work for the entire dataframe

```py
data = data.astype('str')
```

Comment: @Trenton any idea why this way would not cause the issue and OPs way would?

Comment: I suspect there is some issue with the way the name is being called.  Pandas will hide whitespace in a column name, so even copying the column name, may not actually work.  I'd need to see the actual csv to verify.

Answer (score 1):

If need all columns to strings better is use parameter `dtype` in `read_csv`:

```
data = pd.read_csv(filepath, dtype=str)
```

Comment: I don't think this is what she's looking for.  She's only trying to get them as a `str` at the very end, before saving to csv.  She doesn't want the decimal representation in the csv.  Otherwise, yes.

Answer (score 0):

try the below code. A list of index is passed to pandas not the index directly

```
record_ids = data[["RECORD ID"]]
```

Comment: What is this?I didnt get

Comment: data is the pandas data frame right? If you want to access columns from a pandas data frame you can't simply use the index. You need to pass a list of indexes. Here we only need on of them so we use data
[["RECORD ID"]]
 instead of 
data["Record ID"]

Comment: Is this relavant to datatype change?

Comment: am not sure if i got you but it has nothing to do with the column data type

Comment: No, your code not solve problem, only get one column df instead Series if correct column name

Comment: @SaswathMishra using a list like you used is only required when trying to access multiple columns. So it is perfectly fine to say data['RECORD ID'] to access a single column.

Comment: @Ratha it looks like there is a special character somewhere in your column name which is not printing right away. Why not change the column name and remove the space may be like record_id

Comment: Get the column name and check the length of the string to confirm if there are any special characters that are not printing?

Comment: I fixed like what Trenton said in his answer. Thanks guys